# how to get control on scheduler job programatically like start and stop

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

we have requirement like to start, stop and resume individual job and get the status for individual job to display on web page. Please help me on the same to implement this functionality in Quartz Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You should obtain a reference to the quartz `Scheduler` object, and you can do all from there. In spring you can obtain it through `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean`

[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788811/taskscheduler-scheduled-and-quartz/6840970#6840970) for a better spring-quartz support.