# Use @Scheduler in a parent abstract class

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spring-boot, spring-el

I created an abstract class like this:

```
abstract class ScheduledProcess {

  abstract List<String> fetchNewContent()
  abstract List<String> cron()

  //This SPeL doesn't work just stating what kind of expression I'm looking for
  @Scheduled(cron='#{this.cron()}')
  void persistContent(){
     doSomeStuffWithContent(fetchNewContent())
  }

}
```

My goal is to do not repeat myself having to implement the `@Scheduled` method in all subclasses. The `cron()` method returns the specific subclass cron expression. However I'm not finding a way to pass to the annotation the cron value. Maybe I'm just looking at this problem the wrong way.

Comment: Please add the exception/stacktrace/error you're getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is now possible (Spring 4.3.0) you can see it in the issue.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13625

If you are using another Spring version you can write your own beanpostprocessor. You can see an example in the answer given by **quantum** here

[Injecting externalized value into Spring annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608531/injecting-externalized-value-into-spring-annotation)

Comment: `@Scheduled(cron='#{this.cron()}')` is this supported in spring boot ? I am having similar problem

Answer (score 0):

You can't use SpEL there, only property placeholders `${...}`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the why isn't possible to use SpEL? Is a @Scheduled annotation specific restriction? Using property placeholders do you have an idea how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Simply that the `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` has no logic to evaluate a SpEL expression. Such logic would need to be added, with the current bean as the `#root` evaluation object (or otherwise made available as a SpEL variable such as `#currentBean`). No, it can't be done using placeholders. You could write your own bean post processor and use it instead of the standard one; but it requires a good understanding of Spring internals and SpEL.