# Expression in a cron

Tags: java, cron

I want to run a cron in java which will run every 'x' hrs daily. X will be decided by a value in the database which is not static. I tried something like this:

```
private static String cronRunTime = getCronRunTimeFromDb();
private String cronExpression = "* " + cronRunTime + " * * *";
```

But the main problem I am facing is I am not getting how can I configure this value in the @Scheduled annotation.

I tried something:

```
@Scheduled(cron = cronExpression)
    public void myCron(){

    }
```

But I am getting an error during compilation:

```
error: element value must be a constant expression
    @Scheduled(cron = cronExpression)
```

Can someone please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Is your question about "why do I get a compiler error?" or it is more about "how do I configure cron expression scheduled task based on information from database?"

Comment: my question is "how do I configure cron expression scheduled task based on information from database"

Comment: I provided 2 options in my answer below: using Java code and configure task programmatically (using Spring), and declarative way using `@Scheduled` annotation and placeholder capabilities of Spring. You may also drop the Spring way and simply use pure JDK capabilities to run scheduled tasks: `ExecutorService`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

"sec min hour day month weekday"

"0 0 * ? * *" is the cron expression for every hour every day.
"0 0 10 ? * *" is the cron expression for 10am every day.

What you're looking for with every "x" hours every day would be:

"0 0 */x ? * *"

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

According to Java [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1) values of annotation elements for primitive types and `String` must be [constant expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) - something that can be evaluated at compile time, not at runtime.

In short: you cannot pass to an annotation attribute the value that is evaluated at runtime (fetched from database, read from property file, or even returned from a static function like `System.currentTimeMillis()`)

If you have a dynamic logic for your scheduled task that depends on some kind of configuration (in database or property file), you should consider using [ScheduledTaskRegistrar](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/config/ScheduledTaskRegistrar.html) and its `addCronTask(CronTask task)` method, which is of course not as neat as simple annotation.

See example on how to use `ScheduledTaskRegistrar` among responses here:

- [Scheduling a job with Spring programmatically (with fixedRate set dynamically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630539/scheduling-a-job-with-spring-programmatically-with-fixedrate-set-dynamically)

As an alternative you can use a property placeholder logic to populate `cron` attribute of `@Scheduled` annotation as it is described already in other questions:

- [Task scheduling using cron expression from properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306004/task-scheduling-using-cron-expression-from-properties-file)
- [Injecting externalized value into Spring annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608531/injecting-externalized-value-into-spring-annotation)

You can even make Spring to read properties from database if you really gonna go wild, see:

- [Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer load from DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384626/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-load-from-db)
- [How to Load Application Properties from Database](http://www.opencodez.com/java/how-to-load-application-properties-from-database.htm)