# Is Spring's built in Scheduler persistent.?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I have run into a case where I have to use a **persistent Scheduler**, since I have a web application that can crash or close due to some problems and might lose it job details if this happens . I have tried the following:

- **Use Quartz scheduler**:

I used `RAMJobStore` first, but since it isn't persistent, it wasn't of much help. Can't setup `JDBCJobStore` because, this will require huge code changes to my existing code base.
In light of such a scenario, 
I have the following queries:

- If I **use Spring's** built in `@Schedule` annotation **will my jobs be persistent**..? I don't mind if the jobs get scheduled after the application starts. All I want is the jobs to not lose their details and triggers.?
- If **not**, are there **any other alternatives** that can be followed , keeping in mind that I need to schedule multiple jobs with my scheduler.?
- If **yes**, **how can I achieve this**.? My triggers are different each job. For e.g I might have a job that is scheduled at 9AM and another at 8.30AM and so on.
- If **not a scheduler**, then can I have a mechanism to handle this.?

One thing, I found is that the documentation for Quartz isn't very descriptive. I mean it's fine for a top level config, but configuring it on your an application is a pain. This is just a side note. Nothing to do with the question.

Appreciate the help. :)

Comment: Why would using the `JdbcJobStore` requrie a code change?!

Comment: Uhhhh.. wouldn't it..? Can I just set up a properties file for quartz be done with it..?

Comment: Well it would require some configuration on the scheduling and quartz part (and you probably cannot use @Scheduled anymore because you need to use the Quartz `Job` interface.). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788811/taskscheduler-scheduled-and-quartz/6840970#6840970 has some references.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@Schedule` has nothing to do with the actual executor. The default java executors aren't persistent (maybe there are some app-server specific ones that are), if you want persistence you have to use [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) for job execution.

Answer (score 11):

1. No, Spring's @Schedule-annotation will typically only instruct Spring at what times a certain task should be scheduled to run within the current VM. As far as I know there is not a context for the execution either. The schedule is static.
2. I had a similar requirement and created db-scheduler (https://github.com/kagkarlsson/db-scheduler), a simple, persistent and cluster-friendly scheduler. It stores the next execution-time in the database, and triggers execution once it is reached.

A very simple example for a `RecurringTask` without context could look like this:

```
final RecurringTask myDailyTask = ComposableTask.recurringTask("my-daily-task", Schedules.daily(LocalTime.of(8, 0)),
                () -> System.out.println("Executed!"));

final Scheduler scheduler = Scheduler
        .create(dataSource)
        .startTasks(myDailyTask)
        .threads(5)
        .build();

scheduler.start();
```

It will execute the task named `my-daily-task` at 08:00 every day. It will be scheduled in the database when the scheduler is first started, unless it already exists in the database.

If you want to schedule an ad-hoc task some time in the future **with** context, you can use the `OneTimeTask`:

```
    final OneTimeTask oneTimeTask = ComposableTask.onetimeTask("my-onetime-task",
            (taskInstance, context) -> System.out.println("One-time task with identifier "+taskInstance.getId()+" executed!"));

    scheduler.scheduleForExecution(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1), oneTimeTask.instance("1001"));
```

3. See the example above. Any number of tasks can be scheduled, as long as task-name and instanceIdentifier is unique.